# Can anyone explain me the output of this code?

Tags: c

```
char c[] = "hello"; 

printf("%*d", c);
```

**the output is :**

infinite loop of spaces

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the `printf` doc? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: You probably meant to do something like `printf("%*s",10, c);`.

Comment: @Jose cplusplus.com might not be the best reference. You'd rather link to the correct website for C++ documentation, although the questioner uses C. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: @Andreas The link is C11 and C++11 compliant: [...those listed here are supported by the latest C and C++ standards...], but there is no doubt that there are more good references.

Answer (score 11):

> Can anyone explain me the output of this code?
>
> infinite loop of spaces

```
char c[] = "hello";

printf("%*d", c);
```

the `%*d` say the first arg after the format indicates the width, here it is the address of *c* interpreted as a huge number, and the default added character to respect the width is a space.

note there is a missing arg normaly giving the value to print

---

if I use a valid code like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%0*d\n", 3, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

the result is 001 because I ask for to write '1' with a width of 3 and the added character is '0'

Answer (score 0):

**c is an array of char which holds hello** but what is an array. **it is a pointer with a chunk of memory** mean above we create an array means **we create a pointer whose point blocks of memory which hold hello string** like c variable. it means c contain Adresse of the first block of hello.

### now we look into `printf("%*d")`

> `printf("%*d")`  `*`  represent the width and second parameter d represent a integer

### u can see that how `*` symbol work in below example

`printf("output is:%*c",3,c): its output:'   h'`

> **here is width three and print a char which hold c and that is h**

now see why screen has infinite loop let's see `printf("%'*'d",c)`

> **we know the first argument is the width and second output is data here our first argument is c which is an array and u know array hold address of the first block**
> Code executed it give an address to width and **u know the address is too long and it sometimes negative then why your screen has too much space not infinite because u give width as a long as a address** further doubt comment me

Comment: Some punctuation marks would be helpful. It is pretty hard to read and to understand.

Comment: Because English is not my mother tongue 